# Missing "jump to source" button on TeXtudio

Tags: pdf, texstudio

I use texstudio-miktex on windows 10pro.

**I have a file named "epanalhptika.tex" that "jump to source" button is missing.**

**1)** As you can see, the name has no blanks or special characters.

**2)** The file epanalhptika.synctex.gz exists at the document's folder.

**3)** I compile the document frequently.

But when I delete pictures or fancy boxes, all become alright! *The "jump to source button" appears again!*

What's happening?

Thank's for your attention!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - No problem with your filename. Try to remove all auxiliary files and compile again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution! The file was saved in a folder named with Greek characters!